# "44 hundred" instead of "4 thousand and 4 hundred"

Tags: numbers, reading-aloud, numerals

Could you please tell me if it is okay to speak this way:

- I have 12 hundred dollars left in my pocket.
- There are 10 hundred words in the text.

I've taken this from the TV series "The 4400".

Comment: Hellion's answer there says "once you go above 1900, you generally wouldn't use that form on a number that's not an even multiple of 100" but note that in this case your examples are even multiples of 100, so people would say "12 hundred" or "44 hundred". But "ten hundred" is a bit weird though in my opinion, since "a thousand" is just as short to say.

Comment: Also related ELU questions: [Is it improper English to read the number 1100 as “eleven hundred”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145767), [Is it proper grammar to refer to four digit number in hundreds?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7953), [Is there a standard for speaking “1500” as “one thousand five hundred” versus “fifteen hundred”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142227)

Comment: _Twelve hundred dollars in my pocket_ is fine. _Ten hundred words in the text_ is not okay, although _eleven hundred words_ and _nine hundred words_ would both be okay.

Comment: *Ten hundred* is *a thousand* so why not?

Comment: @SovereignSun If you have an even multiple of ten hundreds (ten hundred, twenty hundred, thirty hundred, etc.) we count in thousands instead.  Otherwise, counting in hundreds is okay from one hundred to ninety-nine hundred.

Comment: @snailplane Okay, I see. I understand.